# AssertJ: Best way for matching collection of objects against to the collection of conditions/assertions

Tags: java, assertj

I am looking for a convenient way of matching list of objects to list of
conditions or assertions in a way that all records could be in any order, but all of them should match to all specified conditions. Specific object to specific condition.

Example:

I have list of objects, that could be fetched in arbitrary order.
Let's say of the following type:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Integer age;
}
```

```
Person A is Bobby, 34y
Person B is John, 15y
```

And I have list of conditions that I expect to match.

```
Condition personA = new Condition<>(p -> p.name.equals("Bobby"), "Person A");
Condition personB = new Condition<>(p -> p.name.equals("john"), "Person B");
```

And now I would like to have some operator that will take a list of persons, and match each person to list of conditions. One of condition should pass, otherwise - assertion fail.
Order of persons and conditions could be arbitrary.

Is there exists any way how to do this without adding custom implementation?

P.S> I am aware of extracting() method, but think it is not that convenient for comparing complex objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test that at least one of the conditions `personA` and `personB` is met for each one of the elements in the `List <Person>` `personList` as follows:

```
assertThat( personList ).are( anyOf( personA, personB ) );
```

See the [AssertJ documentation](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-conditions).

Note the following imports are required:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.anyOf;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
```

Comment: An alternative without condition would be [`anyMatch`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)).